# Can't use some Controller names in Zend 1.11?

Tags: zend-framework, naming-conventions, http-status-code-404

When making a new module in my Zend Application I got a 404 error. Just "404 Page not Found", no error report or anything.

This is the controller class

```
class Overig_PwshController extends AuthController
```

That one doesn't work when I visit the url localhost/test/src/public/overig/pwsh

Now when I change it to this it works!

```
class Overig_TestController extends AuthController
```

That one does work when visiting localhost/test/src/public/overig/test

Why? I'm stumped!

Note: I have another Controller called

```
class Overig_PwswController extends AuthController
```

which also works perfectly.

Comment: We'll need more info about your routing and file structure of your app to be able to answer definitively, but the most likely cause is the filename of the controller classes (which are case sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

Using the default routing in Zend Framework (v1.x), I always forget how certain URL patterns map to action and view-script names. So just a quick post, mostly for myself, to record them here.

```
URL: mycontroller/test-me
Controller: mycontroller
Action: testMe
Script: test-me.phtml

URL: mycontroller/testMe
Controller: mycontroller
Action: testme
Script: test-me.phtml
```

That’s it!

You can also follow same for controller name to build your url and controller name.

let me know if i can help you more.